# How to redirect from one WP site to another

Tags: redirect, wp-redirect

I want to set it up so when you click on a tab on my one site it redirects you to my other site.  I've tried every code I can think of and nothing seems to work.

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at your WordPress Admin > Appearances > Menus

You can add a custom link to your other site and it will appear in your menu

[image]

Comment: Just tried that and it gave me an error message "Server not found"  but if I type it in myself in the address bar the new site comes up fine.

Comment: @GerryS It's a weird behaviour. May be a typo? What's your site URL and the URL you are trying to redirect to?

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can make a banner ad on your side and link to your site. The best way to do it because users will get attention and moreover visitors will think that your site has an Banner Advertiser as well.